# VBA Excel - How to retrieve cell from hyperlinked file in master admin

Tags: excel, vba

I have a two folders that contain information submitted by a number of tenants. One contains reports (excel files) and the other contains declarations(pdfs). I've created a excel admin file that lists all the tenants. I have another column that uses the following VBA code to indicate if they either submitted a report or a declaration and then hyperlinks to it.

```
Sub IfFileInFolder()

Dim folderPath As String
Dim folderPath2 As String
Dim Ereports As Range, cell As Range


folderPath = "G:\Programs\Ereports\2017\Reports\"

folderPath2 = "G:\Programs\Declarations\"

With Sheets("Tenant Log")
    Set tenant = .Range("B5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In tenant
    If Dir(folderPath & cell.Value & "-report.xlsx") <> "" Then
        cell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell.Offset(0, 14), Address:=folderPath & cell.Value2 & "-report.xlsx"
        cell.Offset(0, 14).Value = "REPORTED"

    ElseIf Dir(folderPath2 & cell.Value & "-declaration.pdf") <> "" Then
        cell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell.Offset(0, 14), Address:=folderPath2 & cell.Value2 & "-declaration.pdf"
        cell.Offset(0, 14).Value = "DECLARED"

    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 14).Value = "INCOMPLETE"

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

However, for the reports, there is a money value I would like to copy and paste to beside where it lists "REPORTED" in my admin file. I've tried the following code (and many variations) to get the number, but receive Run time error '1004'.

```
Sub retrieve()

With Sheets("Tenant Log")
Set fee = .Range("P5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In fee
If cell = "REPORTED" Then
cell.Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
Sheets("4. Estimated fees").Range("I15").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.Close
cell.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
Else
    cell.Value2 = "N/A"
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Can someone please let me know how I can avoid this error and get the values extracted from each tenant report?

Comment: what line do you get the error on?

Comment: Hi Bruce- It opens the first tenant sheet and then the "'1004 error': Application-defined or object-defined error" pops up. Maybe there is a way I can retrieve the fee information for each tenant from its listing name in the admin file and the report file extension instead of using the hyperlinks created from the first run of code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to move macro to macro sheet instead of inside the admin file for some reason.